# CoreUI React dashboard routing not working after implementing Google OAuth

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-oauth

So, I just fixed my app so that after there is success logging in, the home page should display. However, after this, the rest of my routing has seemed to magically disappear. Here is the relevant code:

DefaultLayout.js

```
class DefaultLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       name:'',
       redirect: false,
   };
}

componentDidMount() {
     let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('userData'));
     console.log(data);
}

  render() {
    if(!sessionStorage.getItem('userData') || this.state.redirect){
    return (<Redirect to={'/404'}/>)
}

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader fixed>
          <DefaultHeader />
        </AppHeader>
        <div className="app-body">
          <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
            <AppSidebarHeader />
            <AppSidebarForm />
            <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} />
            <AppSidebarFooter />
            <AppSidebarMinimizer />
          </AppSidebar>
          <main className="main">
            <AppBreadcrumb appRoutes={routes}/>
            <Container fluid>
              <Switch>
                {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                    return route.component ? (<Route key={idx} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} name={route.name} render={props => (
                        <route.component {...props} />
                      )} />)
                      : (null);
                  },
                )}
                <Redirect from="/home" to="/dashboard" />
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </main>
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
       this.state = {
       loginError: false,
       redirect: false
};
this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
}
signup(res, type) {
  let postData;
  if (type === 'google' && res.w3.U3) {
  postData = {
    email: res.profileObj.email,
    name: res.profileObj.name,
    googleId: res.profileObj.googleId,
    googleAccessToken: res.Zi.access_token,
    googleImageURL: res.profileObj.imageURL
  };
 }


if (postData) {
  PostData('v1/zuulusers', postData).then((result) => {
     let responseJson = result;
     sessionStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(responseJson));
     this.setState({redirect: true});
  });
  } else {}
}
render() {

  if (this.state.redirect || sessionStorage.getItem('userData')) {
    return (<Redirect to={'/home'}/>)
}
const responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log("google console");
  console.log(response);
  this.signup(response, 'google');
}

    return (


      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="5">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="text-white py-5 d-md-down-none" style={{ width: '44%' }}>
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Login if you dare</h2>
                      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatif-assets-cdn/images/asset_1+copy2.png" alt="zuul logo" id="zuul_logo" className="mx-auto d-block rounded img-avatar"/>
                          <GoogleLogin
                            clientId="24656564867-3issjp4bq0gsr05banuomnniilngiicc.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                            buttonText="Login with Google"
                            onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                            onFailure={responseGoogle}
                          />
                    </div>
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route  path="/home" name="Home Page" component={DefaultLayout} />
          <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404} />
          <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500} />
          <Route exact path="/" name="login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

And then this is a small section of code to show how the routing is set up in CoreUI:

routes.js

```
const LoadingButtons = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Buttons/LoadingButtons'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Charts = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Charts'),
  loading: Loading,
});

const Dashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./views/Dashboard'),
  loading: Loading,
});
const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Login', component: Login, exact: true },
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: DefaultLayout, exact: true},
  { path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
```

For some reason, after the homepage loads, it doesn't load any of the other pages. They just come up blank but the path is defined in the URL. Not sure what I m doing wrong in routing.

Comment: Any specific reason for logging in from front-end? Also, Hide you API keys or change it (if you haven't done it already)

Comment: @KuchBi they just want to use Google OAuth as the authorization agent

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a sandbox Version? Also, Here is something which I think is wrong from quick observation, You have done something like this

```
 <GoogleLogin
     clientId="24656564867-3issjp4bq0gsr05banuomnniilngiicc.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      buttonText="Login with Google"
      onSuccess={responseGoogle}
       onFailure={responseGoogle}
   />
```

And your **responseGoogle** happens to be in `render()` which is again wrong since you don't want it to be rendered every time your state changes and rather want it when someone clicks on GoogleLogin button

Second, When you do something like this

```
onSuccess={responseGoogle}
onFailure={responseGoogle}
```

You are referencing your variable and not calling it.

If you ask me, I will suggest you to declare your

```
const responseGoogle = (response) => {
  console.log("google console");
  console.log(response);
  this.signup(response, 'google');
}
```

**Outside the render** and then call it by changing your

```
 <GoogleLogin
      clientId="24656564867-3issjp4bq0gsr05banuomnniilngiicc.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      buttonText="Login with Google"
       onSuccess={this.responseGoogle}
       onFailure={this.responseGoogle}
 />
```

Ps: Notice I have changed `responseGoogle` to `this.responseGoogle`
Also, I am hoping you have configured/added host address and redirect URL in Google Oauth?

Ps: There is just so much code to comprehend, You need to think about posting the code which is relavent